# How do I consume a C#/WinRT component with WinUI3 controls and async code and consume it from a C++/WinRT app that uses the Windows App SDK?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, winui-3

I'm trying to upgrade an existing C# UWP `UserControl` I have to be used by WinUI3 C++ and WinUI3 C#.

It's awesome, I'm using a shared code project to compile it for UWP and WinUI3 everything is great except I can't seem to execute async code in my WinUI C++ test app. It just dies I can't even wrap it in a try/catch.

I decided to strip my problem down to the basics and followed along with [this tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/create-winrt-component-winui-cswinrt) and everything is great until I change the button click event to

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

WinUI3 C++ just dies as soon as it hits the async line with

> Unhandled exception at 0x75F39132 (KernelBase.dll) in CppApp.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x8001010E, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x5D850000).

Anything I try like `Wait()` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` or `GetAsyncAction()` doesn't seem to work.

The WinUI3 C# app that references the same project has no issues.
I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

How do I write async code in C# for consumption in C++?

Comment: I suggest you could follow the Doc:[Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to run async C# in C++ so I compiled another DLL specific to C++ that removes async.

Eg.

```
Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(5000)).Wait();
```